# Extract common functions from 2 functors

Tags: module, ocaml, functor

I have defined a module type `ZONE` and two functors (`ZoneFun` and `ZoneFunPrec`) to build it:

```
(* zone.ml *)
module type ZONE =
sig
  type info
  type prop
  type t = { p: prop; i: info }
  val f1 : t -> string
end

module ZoneFun (Prop : PROP) = struct
  type info = { a: int }
  type prop = Prop.t
  type t = { p: prop; i: info }
  let f1 z = "f1"
end

(* zoneFunPrec.ml *)
module ZoneFunPrec (Prop: PROP) (Prec: ZONESM) = struct
  type info = { a: int; b: Prec.t }
  type prop = Prop.t
  type t = { p: prop; i: info }
  let f1 z = "f1"
  let get_prec z = z.info.prec
end
```

Some functions in these 2 functors are implemented differently (e.g. `f0`); some functions are exactly the same (e.g. `f1`). My question is how to extract those common functions to avoid from implementing them twice?

**Edit:** (I realize that I need to give more specific information to make it clearer... Sorry about the change...)

There are some differences between `ZoneFun` and `ZoneFunPrec`:

1) their `type info` are not same
2) `ZoneFunPrec`  has `get_prec` that `ZoneFun` doesn't have, and the signture of `ZONE` doesn't require it.

So later I can write `module ZoneB = ZoneFun(B)` and `module ZoneA = ZoneFunPrec(C)(ZonesmD)` to build the zones...

Comment: As in best practices to refactor your code? Or are you looking for something automated or an answer involving reflection?

Comment: A solution of re-factoring my code will be OK, but there are lots of same functions from these 2 functors, I just want to write them once for all...

Comment: If you create one module with the common functions then either 1) use 'include' to export it within each module 2) 'open' the module in both. It just depends on how those subset of functions are being used.

Comment: The thing is that these functions require `Zone.t` (e.g. `f1`), so if I add another module, I am not quite sure about the order of compilation...

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
module ZoneFunPrec (Prop: PROP) = struct
  module Zone1 = ZoneFun(Prop)
  type prop = Prop.t
  type t = string
  let f0 x = "f0 in ZoneFunPrec"
  let f1 = Zone1.f1
end
```

But this will only work if you do not ascribe the signature in the functor

```
module ZoneFunPrec (Prop: PROP) : ZONE = ...
```

If you want opaque ascription, you could do something like this

```
(* No ascription here *)
module SharedFn (Prop : PROP) = struct
  type prop = Prop.t
  type t = string
  let f0 x = "f0 in ZoneFun"
  let f1 x = "f1"
end

(* Ascribe the module to hide the types *)  
module ZoneFun (Prop : PROP) : ZONE = struct
  module Shared = SharedFn(Prop)
  let f1 = Shared.f1
  ...defs specific to ZONE...
end 

module ZoneFunPrec (Prop: PROP) : ZONE_PREC = struct
  module Shared = SharedFn(Prop)
  type prop = Prop.t
  type t = string
  let f0 x = "f0 in ZoneFunPrec"
  let f1 = Shared.f1
  ...defs specific to ZONE_PREC...
end
```

You can try using `include Shared` to save typing, but the types will be abstract so it won't be very flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the signature of `ZoneFunPrec` is not same as `ZoneFun`, this complicates the thing...

Comment: Before I could use `module ZoneA = ZoneFunPrec(A)(ZonesmB)` to build a module `ZoneA`, but I don't see how this code would be, if your suggestion is adapted... Could you please write a little bit more for the part `...defs specific to ZONE_PREC`?

Comment: I just changed a little bit OP to make it clearer, sorry about it... I think we are quite close to the solution...